# Deploying a Flask app on Vercel is showing 404 Not Found

Tags: python, html, flask, web, vercel

My project structure:

```
api
 |
 |--fsk.py (file)
 |
 |--static (folder)
 |    |
 |    |--css (folder containing css files)
 |    |
 |    |--scripts (folder containing js files)
 |   
 |--templates (folder containing html files)
 |      
 |--vercel.json (file)
 |
 |--requirements.txt (file)
```

The contents of the files are as follows:-

vercel.json:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./fsk.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python"
    },
    {
      "src": "./static/**",
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    },
    {
      "src": "./templates/**",
      "use": "@vercel/templates
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "./templates/index.html"
    }
  ],
  "outputdirectory": "templates"
}
```

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==2.2.2
```

The file fsk.py contains render_templates. For example:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')
```

I tried to search on Google, but did not find any tutorial/example that shows how to deploy a flask app using render_template on Vercel.

**Note**: I am not using `app.run()` in fsk.py. Should I use it?

Comment: Have you tried "outputdirectory": static?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't work though.